# PHP Build Tree with ul tag

Tags: php

I have the following php array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

)
```

In which the first keys ( 0 , 1 , 2 , 4 ) are the IDs that contains childrens.

**Everything starts from the key 0 which is the parent for all the others.**

I want to build a tree ***using ul li tags*** from this array. I searched the site i found similar topics but then i noticed my method isn't the same.

I tried to do it and failed.

### EDIT

This is what i have so far:

```
function PrintTree( $arr )
{
    global $names;

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ( $arr as $key => $childrens )
    {
        if ( $key == 0 and is_array( $childrens ) )
        {
            PrintTree( $childrens );
            continue;
        }

        if ( is_array( $childrens ) )
        {
            echo "<li><a href=\"#\">" . $names[$key] . "</a>";
            PrintTree( $childrens );
            echo "</li>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<li><a href=\"#\">" . $names[$childrens] . "</a></li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

The above code fails and produces this:

```
Root 
      Item 1
      Item 2
   Item 1
      Item 3
   Item 2
      Item 4
   Item 4
      Item 5
```

But the correct tree should be:

```
Root 
     Item 1
         Item 3
     Item 2
         Item 4
             Item 5
```

Thank you

Comment: What method are you using? Code please.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i edited my first post

Comment: You should be using `$this->` instead of `self::`, since self refers to the class and $this to the current instance.

Comment: How exactly did you fail? Any error messages?

Comment: Hello sorry for the mess, just a bit tired today. working all day. I fixed my first post again. Should be ok now.

Comment: I'm not even sure what the relationship is between the input array and the desired output

Comment: There is a relationship just needs different parsing than the usual one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this snippet should work :

```
$foo = [
    0 => [1,2],
    1 => [3],
    2 => [4],
    4 => [5],
];

function track($array, $index = 0) {
    $out = '<ul>';
    if (isset($array[$index]) && is_array($array[$index])) {
        foreach($array[$index] as $track) {
            $out .= '<li>'.$track;
            $out .= track($array, $track);
            $out .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    $out .= '</ul>';
    return $out;
}

echo track($foo);
```

Comment: YES! Working. Thank you boss